# R shiny use multiple variable in a function

Tags: r, shiny

Sorry in advance for my english, I'm french.

I currently developed a GUI for an R package. And my problem is that I want to leave the user the choice of the variable to use for create the model.
The following is a simplified version of what the code looks like:

```
library(shiny)
library(frailtypack)

data("readmission", package = "frailtypack")

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("var", "variable",
              names(readmission), multiple = TRUE),
  selectInput("group", "variable in cluster()",
              names(readmission)),
  verbatimTextOutput("modjoint")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$modjoint <- renderPrint({
    print(
      modSha <-
        frailtyPenal(
          Surv(t.start, t.stop, event) ~ cluster(get(input$group)) + sex + dukes +
            charlson,
          data = readmission,
          n.knots = 6,
          kappa = 5000,
          recurrentAG = TRUE,
          cross.validation = TRUE
        )
    )

  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

sex, dukes and charlson are variables of readmission. But I want the user to choose among all the variables of readmission.

How can I replace "sex+dukes+charlson" by the input "var"?

Many thanks

Comment: Build your formula as a string, something like `as.formula(paste("Surv(t.start,t.stop,event)~cluster(get(input$group)) + ", paste(var, collapse = " + ")))`.

Comment: Thank you for the speed of your answer. It works